# Digital Asset Management tool for large files that are not photos or videos

Tags: assets, git-lfs, dam, git-annex

Most DAMs that I have found are geared towards media like photos and videos.  I have need to manage large binary files like ISOs and IMG files.

Does anybody know of a DAM that can manage non-media files?  Specifically something that is on premise?  Going to a DAM in the cloud would be too expensive because of the amount of storage we would need and the bandwidth it would consume.

Comment: I recently discovered GitLab and [git-annex](https://about.gitlab.com/2015/02/17/gitlab-annex-solves-the-problem-of-versioning-large-binaries-with-git/).  I am going to try managing our files GitLab and git-annex.  If it works like I think it should, I will let you guys know.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

We solved our need by using Git Large File Storage (LFS) to manage our large binary files. We tried out git-annex as well, which worked well, but in the end we went with Git LFS.

Answer (score 0):

DAMs have specific functionality tailored towards visual content. For example, DAM systems will create previews for the files stored and also, possibly, extract metadata from the file itself. In addition to that, it will also provide you options to transform and download content in various formats. Considering that all these options are part of the DAM package, I would not expect too much from them with respect to previews, metadata extraction and transformations when it comes to large binary files, such as ISO and IMG files.

You can however, use most of the DAMs to upload any file you want. It will simply take it and allow you to tag metadata against it. An example would be [Elvis DAM](http://www.getelvisdam.com) where you can simply upload content (I would use hot folder type of uploads for large files) and tag them with metadata. You can create custom fields such as OS version, applications, etc. and store it against the ISO files. These will become searchable and it will scale to hold all of this information and allow you to quickly find your content.

There might be other simpler and less expensive solutions out there that might just simply keep a file and assign metadata to it.

Comment: DAMs can be used for any digital asset, not just images.  That they are more often used for visual assets is an artifact that it's hard for a computer to pull descriptions out of images.  But large offices use them for taming their bureaucratic paperwork; for connecting related documents (E.g. all the building permits issued for a given property)

Answer (score 0):

Try NeoFinder
It's original incarnation was as a catalog program for CDs, but it supports extensive metadata for tagging, as well as pulling metadata from images.

https://www.cdfinder.de